# Find contents inside a tensor if iteration is not allowed

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have been trying to expand a tensor of x and y coordinates in a point cloud to see it's contents, but all I can get is the shape of the tensor and its type.

(Something like this :

```
x_interior_1 = domain_invar['Interior1']['x']
print(x_interior_1)
y_interior_1 = domain_invar['Interior1']['y'] 
print(y_interior_1)
```

Result:

```
Tensor("x_2:0", shape=(10000, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("y_2:0", shape=(10000, 1), dtype=float32)
```

)

When I run an iterator over it, I'm greeted with iteration not allowed.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. 
Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
```

So I do it. I put the decorator above the def. But then, I'm greeted with this:

```
  @tf.function
  def custom_loss(self, domain_invar, pred_domain_outvar, true_domain_outvar, step):
    # get points on interior of rec
    x_interior_1 = domain_invar['Interior1']['x']
    print([x for x in x_interior_1])
    y_interior_1 = domain_invar['Interior1']['y']
    print([y for y in y_interior_1])
    area_interior_1 = domain_invar['Interior1']['area']
    x_interior_2 = domain_invar['Interior2']['x']
    y_interior_2 = domain_invar['Interior2']['y']
    area_interior_2 = domain_invar['Interior2']['area']
```

Result:

```
    return _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.Flatten(nested, expand_composites)
    TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Key' and 'Key'
```

What does one do to see what's inside??

Comment: does `[x for x in x_interior_1.numpy()]` work?

Comment: @christian-steinmeyer no :( same old `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Key' and 'Key'`

Comment: Hi @mayank list comprehensions are not supported in autographs. In that case you have to use [tf.map_fn()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn). For more details please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/e29f66f60718b923a413f4a41699098c). Thank You.